# Where does the network code exist

Tags: networking, operating-system

Where in the system does the code for various TCP/IP layers exist.In what language it is and how can we view this

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the operating system in question, but it'd mostly be implemented in the kernel. A couple of examples: Windows is closed source, and thus you can't inspect its networking code, but for Linux, which is written in C, you can easily browse its code on [GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux).